# Database-Migration (Activiti 5.16.4 to Camunda)

Tags: migration, activiti, camunda

I am trying to migrate Activiti 5.16.4 to Camunda 7.3.0-Final.
Everything worked fine until I tried to start my JBoss. I get the message:

```
### The error may exist in org/camunda/bpm/engine/impl/mapping/entity/Job.xml
### The error may involve org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.JobEntity.selectNextJobsToExecute-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: select * from ( select a.*, ROWNUM rnum from (     select       RES.*      from ACT_RU_JOB RES      where (RES.RETRIES_ > 0)       and (RES.DUEDATE_ is null or RES.DUEDATE_ <= ?)       and (RES.LOCK_OWNER_ is null or RES.LOCK_EXP_TIME_ < ?)       and (RES.SUSPENSION_STATE_ = 1 or RES.SUSPENSION_STATE_ is null)                      ) a where ROWNUM < ?) where rnum  >= ?
### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "RES"."SUSPENSION_STATE_": ungültiger Bezeichner
```

I don't really know what could help you to solve this, maybe someone has experienced the same issue.
Just let me know, whether you need to get more information.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a look at the Camunda database creation scripts for 7.3.0 [1] and then write yourself a SQL script that migrates your schema, i.e. that adds all missing tables and columns.

[1] https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/tree/7.3.0/engine/src/main/resources/org/camunda/bpm/engine/db/create